# Sent actions and Received actions in cocoa interface builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, event-handling, interface-builder

What is the difference between received actions and sent actions in the Interface builder UI ? I am confused between the two while adding events for UI control

Answer (score 4):

Sent actions (in OS X Cocoa each `NSView` will normally have one), perform a selector (Typically an `IBAction`) upon something like a button press, or end editing, etc.

Received actions is the exact opposite-- it shows you which objects are requesting an action from the object.

When you create one, the other will automatically be created in the other object involved.

For example, if you create an `IBAction` in your implementation file (file owner of your nib), then connect this `IBAction` to the `Sent Action` for an `NSButton` in your xib.  You can see that connection in your `NSButton's` `Sent Action` section, and you will see that connection as well in your `File's Owner` -> `Received Actions`.

Likewise, you could instead of connecting the `NSButton` to the `IBAction` in your `File's Owner` object-- if you first define the `IBOutlet` in your implementation, you will see that selector in your `Received Actions`.  You can then connect that to your `NSButton`, and the same result will be achieved.